# Sequelize query with Where and Include failing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Trying to get a query to return cars and assocaited photos. This works:

```
Vehicle.findAll({
        include: [db.photos]
    })
```

and I get an output like:

```
{
    "id": 69,
    "make": "Ford",
    "model": "Fiesta",
    "photos": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "photoUrl": "29_1.jpg",
            "vehicleId": 69
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "photoUrl": "29_2.jpg",
            "vehicleId": 69
        }
    ]
},
```

But this does not, returning the car data only without the photos:

```
Vehicle.findAll({
        where: { 
            make: { [Op.like]: '%' + make + '%' },
            model: { [Op.like]: '%' + model + '%' }
        }
    },
    {
        include: [db.photos]
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing 2 objects to `findAll`.  put `where` in the same object as `include`.

Comment: So simple but very helpful - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use `Model.findAll()` correctly. The signature of `Model.findAll()` is

[public static async findAll(options: object): Promise<Array>](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll)

As you can see, it accepts only one parameter `options`.

Try:

```js
Vehicle.findAll({
  where: {
    make: { [Op.like]: '%' + make + '%' },
    model: { [Op.like]: '%' + model + '%' },
  },
  include: [db.photos],
});
```